# Pandas Multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I am trying to create a table in pandas dataframe, with Multiindex column:

```
multicol1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Loan Summary', 'Current Balance'),
                                   ('Loan Summary', 'Count')])
df_multi_level_cols1 = pd.DataFrame([756431, 5],
                                columns=multicol1)
```

But I can't understand what I am doing wrong:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 1), indices imply (2, 2)
```

The desired output is like this, so the "Loan Summary" is a header of the table:

```
      Loan Summary
Current Balance    Count
    756431         5
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `[]` in your input `list`

```
df_multi_level_cols1 = pd.DataFrame([[756431, 5]],
                                    columns=multicol1)
df_multi_level_cols1
     Loan Summary      
  Current Balance Count
0          756431     5
```